# Erlang check .pem certificate is not revoked with .crl file

Tags: ssl, erlang

I am trying to implement offline check for certificate based on data from .CRL (certificate revoked list) files

---

I checked [pkix validation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/public_key.html#pkix_crls_validate-3) and [crl api](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl_crl_cache_api.html#fresh_crl-2) but did not find any examples of using

---

Assume I have list of providers, list of CRL files of provider (revoked and partially revoked), and some .pem file to check

---

Any ideas how this check should be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `crl_check` and `crl_cache` options:

```
ssl:connect("www.google.com", 443,
  [{verify, verify_peer},
   {crl_check, true},
   {crl_cache, {ssl_crl_hash_dir, {internal, [{dir, "/path/to/crls/"}]}}}]).
```

The `ssl_crl_hash_dir` module expects to find a directory containing all CRLs with file names in a very specific format, e.g. `1a2b3c4d.r0`, where the first eight characters are a hash of certain parts of the certificate, and the trailing `.r0` is a CRL revision number.  The [c_rehash utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/c_rehash.1ssl.html), which comes with OpenSSL, can set up symlinks matching that format.

`ssl_crl_hash_dir` lets you do CRL checks completely offline, unlike `ssl_crl_cache`, which attempts to download CRLs from the designated server.

---

To prepare the CRL directory, let's say we downloaded Google's CRL:

```
wget http://crl.pki.goog/GTSGIAG3.crl
```

Unfortunately, it's in DER format, so `c_rehash` doesn't understand it (and neither will `ssl_crl_hash_dir`).  Let's recode it:

```
openssl crl -in GTSGIAG3.crl -inform DER -outform PEM -out GTSGIAG3-pem.crl
```

Now, we can run `c_rehash`, giving the current directory as argument:

```
$ c_rehash .
Doing .
WARNING: GTSGIAG3.crl does not contain a certificate or CRL: skipping
```

It has created two symlinks for us:

```
$ ls -go
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1  16 Jul 23 16:28 6a909d98.r0 -> GTSGIAG3-pem.crl
lrwxrwxrwx 1  16 Jul 23 16:28 a11dd888.r0 -> GTSGIAG3-pem.crl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 635 Jul 23 03:15 GTSGIAG3.crl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 910 Jul 23 16:28 GTSGIAG3-pem.crl
```

The hashes in those symlinks are the ones returned by `openssl crl -hash` and `openssl crl -hash_old`:

```
$ openssl crl -hash -noout -in GTSGIAG3-pem.crl 
6a909d98
$ openssl crl -hash_old -noout -in GTSGIAG3-pem.crl 
a11dd888
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I don't understand the structure of dir "/path/to/crls/" - for example, I already downloaded crl files from acs key providers: revoked_list_provider1.crl, revoked_list_provider2.crl, revoked_list_provider3.crl. And  I have some certificate to check, should I rename one of crl files? Or all with hash r0, new file r1, next r2?

Comment: I updated the answer with some more information about c_rehash. Does that make sense?

Comment: I still don't understand how to ensure that digital signature that I am trying to check in crl files is not revoked. Where this argument should be provided? Is there any way to avoid call openssl and run only erlang functions?

Answer (score 1):

Get serial numbers of revoked certificates:

```
{ok, Bytes} = file:read_file("/Users/Downloads/CA-4E6929B9-Delta.crl").
public_key:der_decode('CertificateList', Bytes).
```

Return

```
 public_key:der_decode('CertificateList', Bytes). 
{'CertificateList',{'TBSCertList',v2,
                                  {'AlgorithmIdentifier',{1,2,804,2,1,1,1,1,3,1,1},
                                                         asn1_NOVALUE},
                                  {rdnSequence,[[{'AttributeTypeAndValue',{2,5,4,10},
                                                                          <<12,28,208,162,208,158,208,146,32,34,208,144,208,160,
                                                                            208,162,...>>}],
                                                [{'AttributeTypeAndValue',{2,5,4,11},
                                                                          <<12,8,208,144,208,166,208,161,208,154>>}],
                                                [{'AttributeTypeAndValue',{2,5,4,3},
                                                                          <<12,49,208,144,208,166,208,161,208,154,32,34,77,65,...>>}],
                                                [{'AttributeTypeAndValue',{2,5,4,5},
                                                                          <<12,14,85,65,45,51,48,52,48,52,55,53,48,...>>}],
                                                [{'AttributeTypeAndValue',{2,5,4,6},<<19,2,85,65>>}],
                                                [{'AttributeTypeAndValue',{2,5,4,7},
                                                                          <<12,8,208,154,208,184,209,151,208,178>>}]]},
                                  {utcTime,"180720162130Z"},
                                  {utcTime,"180720182130Z"},
                                  [{'TBSCertList_revokedCertificates_SEQOF',447646493074184995506808756600724219093179699200,
                                                                            {utcTime,"180715102900Z"},
                                                                            [{'Extension',{2,5,29,21},false,<<10,1,0>>},
                                                                             {'Extension',{2,5,29,24},
                                                                                          false,
                                                                                          <<24,15,50,48,49,56,48,55,49,...>>}]},
                                   {'TBSCertList_revokedCertificates_SEQOF',447646493074184995506808756600724219093196476416,
                                                                            {utcTime,"180715102900Z"},
                                                                            [{'Extension',{2,5,29,21},false,<<10,1,0>>},
                                                                             {'Extension',{2,5,29,24},
                                                                                          false,
                                                                                          <<24,15,50,48,49,56,48,55,...>>}]},
                                   {'TBSCertList_revokedCertificates_SEQOF',447646493074184995506808756600868334281322663936,
                                                                            {utcTime,"180715103000Z"}, ...
```

Check serialNumber of certificate is not in list